# vim system register * and + not working

Tags: vim, copy, freebsd

`:echo has('clipboard')` returns 1, but whenever I execute `"+yy"` or `"*yy"` nothing seems to be in those registers. If I use regular `yy` to copy another line of text, then try to paste from the register using `CONTROL+V` nothing happens. If I try `"+p` vim pastes the line of text I copied using the regular `yy` command.

What's going on here? I'm on FreeBSD by the way.

Comment: Ctrl-V is not `paste` operation in vim. it turns on the visual selection (block). You can try `"+Y` then open other editor, like gedit, if you have, then `Ctrl-V`. you should see the things you copied to vim `+` register on in your clipboard.

Comment: I was reading that ctrl-V is paste in vim if you're in insert mode. Anyway, `"+Y"` doesn't work at all... when I type `:reg` it doesn't even show up as a listed register, and `"+P` as well as `"+p` do nothing.

Comment: you should do `"+Y` not `"+Y"` and do it in Normal mode. Btw, can you tell me how can I find `ctrl-V is paste in vim if you're in insert mode.` in vim help?

Comment: I meant `"+Y`, I am doing it in normal mode. The second quotation mark was a typo. It doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

Comment: what is the output of `set clipboard?`

Comment: clipboard=autoselect,exclude:cons\|linux

Comment: When you have `:set showcmd` and then try one of the commands, do you see the right keys show up in the lower right corner? `"`, `+`, `y`, ...

Comment: @glts, yes, they show up, I see `"+y` and then when I press `y` again the command disappears from the lower right. It seems to be only copying the text into the unnamed register, however.

Comment: @bvpx Do you have `+xterm_clipboard` enabled? `:echo has('xterm_clipboard')`. I'm not sure what this does though ...

Answer (score 22):

Your vim version may not be compiled with X11 clipboard integration.

In vim run the :version command and look for xterm_clipboard in the output. It will be prefixed with a + (supported) or - (unsupported) sign.

Comment: adding to this, neovim ships with all features enabled by default, but if you don't have a clipboard provider, it can't use the system clipboard. running `:checkhealth` will tell you if you're missing a provider. for me, installing `xclip` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me in `Ubuntu 20.04` and `Vim 8.1.2269`

```
sudo apt install vim-gtk3
```

**Explanation**
This package adds support for the `x_term_clipboard` in `vim` if not present already.

*For more info*: [Click Here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31142/31360), [@blankblank's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54269104/10204932).

Answer (score 5):

Another thing that could be going on is your `DISPLAY` environment variable is not being set correctly.  This could happen sometimes if you're running vim from tmux or screen.

Try opening a new terminal, running `echo $DISPLAY`, and then from the terminal running vim, leave vim, execute `export DISPLAY=:0` (but replace :0 with the output from your other terminal), and then re-enter vim and see if clipboard works by doing `"+p`.

Comment: Great, I was using vim from screen. So this solution worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I also met this problem.
My case is that DISPLAY is not set properly in tmux.
And I found a [script](https://gist.github.com/mikeboiko/b6e50210b4fb351b036f1103ea3c18a9) to automatically update tmux DISPLAY.

Answer (score 0):

If you have copy something to clipboard and paste that in vim, you can use `"+p`.

`+` is a quoteplus, which means `CLIPBOARD` documented X selection. `:help quoteplus` for more information.

If you want to copy something in vim to clipboard and paste the content in the other place by `Ctrl+v`, you can do `"+yy`, this will copy the current line to clipboard.

more information about vim register:

```
:help registers
:help quotestar
```

Comment: Sure, but the question is *why* do `"+yy` etc. not do what they should.

Comment: `"+yy` will yank current line to clipboard, including the line break. Just to make sure, Shift and `'` (at the left of enter key), Shift and key `=` (at the left of backspace), y, y.

Comment: `"+yy` doesn't seem copy the current line to clipboard, because when I execute `"+p` it simply pastes whatever is in the unnamed register.

Comment: Copy content to clipboard by `control + v`, for example select your last comment, then type `control + v`, the content will set to clipboard, paste the content in other place by `control + p` to make sure the content is in clipboard. Then type `"+p` in vim, does this work?

Comment: I only have access to this system via ssh through a terminal, there's no GUI. Is there any other way to test this? I really only need to copy and paste things between different instances of Vim without using `vsplit`.

Comment: @bvpx if I'm reading these comments correctly... Youre trying to access the system clipboard over ssh? This will not work easily because vim does not realise it running in an ssh session so it putting the content in the system clipboard of the computer you are sshed into. (You might try http://superuser.com/questions/326871/using-clipboard-through-ssh-in-vim to set up X forwarding so vim does realise its in an ssh session.)

Comment: in my case when I do `:reg`, I dont see the `+` and `*` register at all. Any way to bring it back? I did have these in my register list a while back.. Havent changed my vim distribution since then ..

Answer (score 0):

My problem was my input source `English (US, intl., with dead keys)`, in addition to vim not being compiled with x-clipboard.

I don't face the same issue on windows, but on Ubuntu 20.04 I have to press `"<space>+y` with this input source.

##### Edit:

Seems I can fix this by switching the input source to `English (Intl. with AltGr dead keys)`