# "+ register cannot work in vim with clipboard support

Tags: vim, copy, clipboard, vim-registers

I guess my question may be similar to [vim system register * and + not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18385084/vim-system-register-and-not-working) but my server version is ubuntu. And I'm sure the installed vim has clipboard support. However, I cannot see the `"+` register when I run `:reg` in vim. The followings are the commands I use to diagnose such condition but I still cannot find the solution.

First, I use ssh to connect to this server. To check the availability of clipboard support of Vim:

```
$ vim --version | grep clipboard
+clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
```

However, when I run `:reg` in one file opened by vim, I cannot see the system clipboard register. Here is what I got, (I removed the contents of these registers)

```
:reg
--- Registers ---
""
"0 
"1
"2
"3
"4 
"5 
"6
"7
"8
"9
"q 
"-
": 
"%   /usr/share/vim/vim74/doc/change.txt
"#   new.txt
"/   help registers
```

The os of this server is Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS if this information can be helpful.

Also, I guess I have installed the dependencies of vim with clipboard, here is a subset of what I get when I run `apt list --installed`:

`vim-common/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed]
vim-gnome/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed]
vim-gtk/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed]
vim-gui-common/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2 all [installed,automatic]
vim-runtime/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2 all [installed,automatic]
vim-tiny/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed]
vino/xenial-updates,now 3.8.1-0ubuntu9.2 amd64 [installed]`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/347519/unable-to-copy-from-vim-to-system-clipboard

Comment: Do you have a working X on that server?

Comment: @romainl I'm not sure. Could you be so kind to give more information to check that?

Comment: @phd I tried to `set clipboard=unnamedplus`, and run `set clipboard?` in vim to double check. But I cannot see the `%+` register when I run `:reg`  command.

Comment: The mail advice there is to install `vim-gtk`. I think the advice works because it installs GTK dependencies and they are what make `vim` works with X clipboard.

Comment: @phd I have installed that already. And I have added this to the problem description.

Answer (score 0):

If you **copy your text from your client**, the text is being **copied in the client-clipboard**: `"+@localhost`.
So when using SSH, then starting Vim and type `:reg`, you can **only see serverides registers**, not client-side registers. `"+@server` is empty.

Comment: I'm not convinced that's the reason why the `"+` cannot be shown. Because it should be configured on the server already? Indeed, what I want to do is to copy text in vim with system clipboard on my server, so I could paste the content to another file on the server. I cannot use mouse selection to copy because it would cause many format errors ( like extra spaces, newlines and line numbers shown in vim). Or would you suggest me any other methods to copy and paste easily? Thanks!